# Symfony upgrading 2.1 FOSUserBundle custom registration form Exception

Tags: forms, symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

My custom registration form was working well with the version 1.2.* but when i update symfony in 2.1 and FOSUserBundle in 2.0.*, I've got this problem that I don't know how to resolve.

The error :

> The type name specified for the service "kairos_user.registration_form_type" does not match the actual name. Expected "kairos_user_registration", given "fos_user_registration"

My service definition :

```
services:
    kairos_user.registration_form_type:
        class: Kairos\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: kairos_user_registration }
```

And my config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm #cf kairos doctrine admin
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Kairos\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: kairos_user_registration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias of your registration form service must match the name returned by your registration form type class. In `Kairos\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType` try to change the return value of **getName()** method

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'kairos_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Comment: I reopen this because the FormTypeInterface::getName() is now deprecated, do you have another alternative ?